# I don't understand these directional vectors

Tags: calculus, geometry, vectors, parametric, plane-geometry

I'm currently practicing for my final calculus exam in 20 days time, it has a vector section, here is my problem.

When I need to find these parametric equations for either lines of planes, I need a directional vector, so as you would, take a point and subtract the other point, however these directional vectors cause my final answer to look different to the memos answers. Is there a specific way in which I need to subtract points to get a directional vector, like take the one that looks high in the R3 and subtract a lower one or could they be done in any order, why this is worrying is that the final exam is mostly multiple choice, so I would need it to look like the memos answer.

Comment: No, there is no "right way" to get a directional vector. You should note that if $v$ is one correct choice of directional vector, then any scalar multiple of $v$ will also work. You will need to find one answer, and then compare the options to yours to see which is equivalent.

Comment: So I would really just need to compare the parametric equations then?

Comment: The option that is parallel to the directional vector you get will be the answer.